# How to select a specific item from a collection of items?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

i am using the DataBoundApp template for Windows Phone, and in the template the selectedIndex value is passed from MainPage to DetailsPage to define the data context... like this:

```
    // When page is navigated to set data context to selected item in list
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedIndex = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
        {
            int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
            DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
        }
    }
```

Is this the only way of setting data context or can i select an item with a specific value in it, for example, i would like to set data context to the item which has LineOne = "runtime seven" value...

How can i set that?

EDIT: these are the viewmodel items

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        // Sample data; replace with real data
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime two", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime three", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime four", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime five", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime six", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime seven", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime eight", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime nine", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime ten", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime eleven", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime twelve", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime thirteen", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime fourteen", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime fifteen", LineTwo = "Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis", LineThree = "Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat" });
        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "runtime sixteen", LineTwo = "Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar", LineThree = "Pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" });

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

i don't want to set data context by index number of the item, but by a specific item value

Comment: Show us your array initialization aka your 'collection of items' so we can perhaps help you write it better.  And your question after the code is not the same question as the title, which is it?

Comment: i'm sorry if i wasn't clear enough - i want to select a specific item aka item which has LineOne = "runtime seven" property ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP7, so is LineOne a WP7 thing, or can you provide more details in your code example?

Comment: this is the array, Items is an observable collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can give value the value you are searching for, the below will work.

```
string value = "runtime seven";

DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.LineOne == value);
```

Comment: yeah, that was what i needed, thank you! that will do the trick for now